# Foxconn H-I41-uATX MoBo , CPU upgrade

Tags: hp, cpu, sensors

I'm trying to upgrade my very old motherboard.

My current setup is:

PC : [HP p6710t Desktop](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02697691) with a [Foxconn H-I41-uATX](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01903990) motherboard
  SSD: Samsung 500 GB
  CPU: [Intel E5800](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/42802/intel-pentium-processor-e5800-2m-cache-3-20-ghz-800-mhz-fsb.html)
  RAM: A-Tech 2x2 GB
  OS : Xubuntu 18.04, 64-Bit
  BIOS: 6.05, 8-12-2010

I tried to install E6700 CPU but I get 1 short, 1 long beep at boot-up (memory, BIOS problem??) Same thing with E8600. However, E7600 works with the original 3 GB Samsung RAM only, but I'm missing the extra 1 GB RAM. Any little thing matters with this old PC.

I get zero support from HP, no surprise there. They are not any better then Windows.

Also, E6700 makes system warmer, sometimes in the red zone. I don't know how reliable the sensors are or if they compatible with the old motherboard (again, BIOS??).

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/1055515/new-cpu-bleeps-dont-have-a-clue <--Memory problem. As far as I can see, this is not related to Ubuntu in any way. VTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, old man, but the E6700 and E8600 CPUs are not listed as inter-operable with the motherboard. Your [hardware specs](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01903990) show specific CPUs which are inter-operable:

- Core 2 Quad [Q8xx0/Q9xx0 (Yorkfield core) (95W)](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/codename/26553/yorkfield.html)  [eBay examples](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Q9650-CPU-Processor-Quad-Core-4-Core-3GHz-L2-12MB-LGA-775-Yorkfield-FSB-Bus-95W/283589478572?hash=item42074008ac:g:1RcAAOSwMOtdX2fB)
- Core 2 Duo [E8xx0 (Wolfdale core) (65W)](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/codename/24736/wolfdale.html)
- Core 2 Duo [E7xx0 (Wolfdale core) (65W)](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/codename/24736/wolfdale.html)

But, a lot of cellphone CPUs are faster and cheaper.

As to memory, it takes a pair of 2GB DDR3 non-ECC unbuffered modules:

- PC3-10600 (DDR3-1333) <--- what you have
- PC3-8500 (DDR3-1066), or
- PC3-6400 (DDR3-800)

But, the old BIOS may not let you get at all that memory.

Concerned with heat? I'd remove the heat sink, clear the thermal compound off, and reapply a very thin layer, for compound itself is insulation (just not as bad as air is) intended to fill in the gaps between uneven metal surfaces. You could put a better fan on it, too.

Since your motherboard is uATX, there are [modern uATX motherboards](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=uATX%20DDR4%20motherboard&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_osacat=0&_odkw=uATX%20motherboard) with modern BIOS which work with Ubuntu and take modern CPUs and DDR4 RAM. It may cost less to scrap that old Eton motherboard, CPU, and RAM, and replace them with modern components, but that's really a question for http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com . If you go that route, before you buy, make sure there's Ubuntu drivers for it or it explicitly runs drivers already in Ubuntu.

Comment: This question belongs in http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange,com . You have not been kicked out of here; just this question. More questions about hardware should go there.